# processBuilder failing to load data on different host?

Tags: java, oracle, processbuilder

On host 'A' I start a transaction by inserting values to a table in DB. As soon as I insert, I call `processBuilder` to refresh host 'B' which in-turn should load the updated values from same DB table to cache. But the values are not getting loaded.

Is there any relation between processBuilder and transaction? Because the transaction is yet to complete on the host from where I am calling processBuilder.

I tried fetching values from DB before calling processBuilder on host 'A' and it is returning the values which was recently inserted (result set returns 10 rows) where as on host 'B' which is calling same select statement return 9 rows.

Comment: what type of process is it on HostB?  If it is a java process (or other) it may be using DB Caching and not even read the changed values

Answer (score 1):

"as soon as I insert" red flag.

Yes, there is a relationship between the transaction and processBuilder. If the transaction is not committed, then *all* other sessions will not be able to see the changes. If you're used to programming in a DB app environment where autocommit is enabled and switch to a DB app environment where autocommit is disabled, then you are likely to run across this kind of problem.